# Is there a BLACKLIST Database available containing a list of MD5 digests of malware?

Tags: md5, malware, blacklist, malware-detection

Is there a free or commercial blacklist that I can feel a software that classifies files for bering malware?

Comment: https://isc.sans.edu/tools/hashsearch.html

Comment: Cool, that actually led me to NIST's NSRL...if anybody is interested - go there: http://www.nsrl.nist.gov/new.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [clamav](http://www.clamav.com) signatures. They're in a cvd file. You can extract the md5 signatures from the file.